# how android downloadManager do http basic authentication

Tags: java, android

I want to use android downloadManager to download files; But the url is in http basic authentication. And I can get the user name and password in the application. What should I do to download files from my host?

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

This is my code. I want to download file via "url"; But it need http basic authentication. I want to know how to add authentication like this:

```
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(HOST, 80), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()));
```

Comment: Your question is way too broad, try to narrow down to what are you exactly trying to achieve and what have you tried so far

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the [DownloadManager.Request.addRequestHeader(String header, String value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#addRequestHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method on your `request` object to manually add the HTTP **Authorization** header.

You can read more about the format of this header on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), but basically you just take the username and password, join them with a colon ':' character, then base64-encode the result.

Once you have your encoded credentials, add them to the DownloadManager.Request object with:

```
request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
```