# Android DownloadManager returns error 400 bad request after adding "Authorization" request header

Tags: android, authorization, android-download-manager, http-error, bad-request

The downloading was working fine with this code:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUri));
        request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(localPath)));
```

But we had to switch to authorization token instead of cookie so I replaced this row:

```
        request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
```

with this:

```
        request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", myAuthToken);
```

And now it returns status **FAILED**, reason **400 BAD REQUEST**.

**What I've tried:**

- I used the token in **Retrofit headers** - **works fine**
- I tried to download from **public URIs**, like "http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4" - **works fine**
- I tried

```
myAuthToken.replace(" ", "%20");
```

because there is a single " " in myAuthToken - error **403 Forbidden** 
(This doesn't seem to be a problem, because there is a " " in this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25677680/10227935)

- I tried

```
String encodedToken = Base64.encodeToString(myAuthToken.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**error 403 Forbidden**

- With a wrong/random string used as a token - **error 403 Forbidden**
- I've read here that the error 400 could be connected with the access token: "If this particular session token matches the session token from another request from a different client, the server/application may see this is a malicious act and produce a 400 Bad Request Error code." -
  https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request but I don't have
  any ideas how to fix that
- I've found out that in Apple, there are reserved headers: "If you set a value for one of these reserved headers, the system may ignore the value you set, or overwrite it with its own value, or simply not send it." - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest#1776617

  **Is it possible the "Authorization" header to be non-documented reserved in Android too?**

Currently I've run out of ideas, so I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: I managed to get this error message:
**Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified**
The problem was that the link is a redirect and the Download Manager passes the "Authorization" header in the second request. (The Download Manager doesn't work well with redirects).
I solved the problem making a request with forbidden redirects, getting the actual download location and using this location in the the Download request without the "Authorization" header.